# Looking for a more efficient way to filter an array

Tags: r

I have two arrays I obtained from `krige()`, `values` and `variances` with a couple of million entries. Those two arrays are of the same length and match 1:1 with each other. I want to remove values that have a variance above a certain threshold. I don't really need to modify `values` in-place, generating a third array would be fine.

The following code works fine:

```r
for (i in 1:length(values)) {
  if (variances[i] > 0.8) {
    values[i] = NA
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it is very slow and use only a single processor core. Do I really need to handle the parallel calculations manually? This sounds generic enough so that it should be built-in in some way, not only by using more than one core, but maybe some vector processor instructions?

Please enlighten me.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. It's hard to do anything more than guess without having access to any of your data, knowing anything about its structure, or knowing where `krige` comes from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as those arrays match, you should be able to just subset one with another:

```r
set.seed(1)
(values <- array(1:25, c(5,5)))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
#> [2,]    2    7   12   17   22
#> [3,]    3    8   13   18   23
#> [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
#> [5,]    5   10   15   20   25

(variances <- array(rnorm(25,.8,0.2),c(5,5)))
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#> [1,] 0.6747092 0.6359063 1.1023562 0.7910133 0.9837955
#> [2,] 0.8367287 0.8974858 0.8779686 0.7967619 0.9564273
#> [3,] 0.6328743 0.9476649 0.6757519 0.9887672 0.8149130
#> [4,] 1.1190562 0.9151563 0.3570600 0.9642442 0.4021297
#> [5,] 0.8659016 0.7389223 1.0249862 0.9187803 0.9239651

is.na(values[variances > .8]) <- TRUE

values
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    6   NA   16   NA
#> [2,]   NA   NA   NA   17   NA
#> [3,]    3   NA   13   NA   NA
#> [4,]   NA   NA   14   NA   24
#> [5,]   NA   10   NA   NA   NA
```

For array length of 10 million it takes about a second on my laptop, data generation included:

```r
system.time({
  values <- array(1:10e6, c(1000,10000))
  variances <- array(rnorm(10e6,.8,0.2),dim(values))
  is.na(values[variances > .8]) <- TRUE
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    1.05    0.10    1.14

dim(variances)
#> [1]  1000 10000
object.size(variances)
#> 80000216 bytes
object.size(values)
#> 40000216 bytes
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>